# ¿Se puede centrar un div por medio de CSS y a demás que este en fijo con top:0?

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando y estoy leyendo muchas cosas a la vez y me confunde, he visto lo siguiente por medio de CSS:

```
position : fixed; top : 0;
```

Puedo poner el div pegado en la parte superior pero no logro hacer que además como atributo adicional esté centrado en la pantalla horizontalmente.

¿Cómo podría realizarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
#example {
    position: fixed;
    /* center the element */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* give it dimensions */
    min-height: 10em;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: lo he logrado gracias a tu sugerencia

Comment: @Rick Si la respuesta te ayudo, no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada, asi ayudas a usuarios futuros a encontrar la solución mas facilmente y generas reputación en la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar `top: 0` y `position: fixed` para fijarlo en la parte superior de la pantalla y después usar flexbox y su propiedad `justify-content: center` para centrarlo en la pantalla.

Ejemplo:

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#centrado{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="centrado"></div>
```